# How do I view Multisig Trades using bitcoincore?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, multi-signature

For a school project my goal is to go analyze multisig trades, is there a way where I can make this information any more clear to me?

I have been running bitcoincore as a way to get trades that I can view on my computer, I just don't understand what I am supposed to be looking at. I've put -permitbaremultisig in the settings console, but from there I am at a loss... What I'm looking for would be the wallet addresses of the people doing a multisig trade, but if there is a way that I can see the amount of bitcoin being traded that would be better, as my project depends on the amount of money being traded. If any of you smarter people out there would help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> **What I'm looking for would be the wallet addresses of the people doing a multisig trade,**

If by "trade" you mean "transaction", I don't think that data exists. You can discover something when a multisig output is spent but in something like a 3 of 5 multisig output I think you could, at most, only discover something about three of the five potential signatories.

See [bitcoin multisig address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75722/13866)

By "wallet address" I guess you mean any of the many "addresses" that might be in one or more wallets controlled by the same person or organisation.

Comment: Is there a dead give away in the hash to figure out what transaction would be a multisig transaction? Something that shows it's a 2 to 2 or 2 to 3?

Comment: Nothing in a hash gives any clue to the original data.